# Blink LED without delay with stepper motor

Tags: led, stepper-motor

Based on a [previous question](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/90281/stepper-motor-and-blink-led) I modified the script to use blink without delay.

Unfortunately, it does not work, any idea why?

I am using SparkFun RedBoard Plus, Qwiic LED Stick - APA102C, Adafruit Stepper motor - NEMA-17 size - 200 steps/rev and Adafruit Motor Shield V2.

Modified code (based on @Michel Keijzers, see below):

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Adafruit_MotorShield.h>
#include "Qwiic_LED_Stick.h" // Click here to get the library: http://librarymanager/All#SparkFun_Qwiic_LED_Stick

// Variables will change:
int ledState = LOW;             // ledState used to set the LED

unsigned long previousMillis = 0;        // will store last time LED was updated

// constants won't change:
const long interval = 500;           // interval at which to blink (milliseconds)

LED LEDStick; //Create an object of the LED class

Adafruit_MotorShield AFMS = Adafruit_MotorShield();
Adafruit_StepperMotor *myMotor = AFMS.getStepper(200, 2);

void setup() {
  Wire.begin();
  Serial.begin(115200);
  while (!Serial);
  Serial.println("Stepper test!");



  if (!AFMS.begin()) {
    // if (!AFMS.begin(1000)) {
    Serial.println("Could not find Motor Shield. Check wiring.");
    while (1);
  }
  Serial.println("Motor Shield found.");
  myMotor->setSpeed(50);  // 50 rpm


  //Start up communication with the LED Stick
  if (!LEDStick.begin())  {
    Serial.println("Qwiic LED Stick failed to begin. Please check wiring and try again!");
    while (1);
  }

  Serial.println("Qwiic LED Stick ready!");
//  LEDStick.setLEDColor(255, 0, 0);
  LEDStick.setLEDBrightness(1);
}

void loop() {
  unsigned long currentMillis = millis();

  if (currentMillis - previousMillis >= interval) {
    // save the last time you blinked the LED
    previousMillis = currentMillis;

    ledState = !ledState;
    // set the LED with the ledState of the variable:
    uint8_t intensity = ledState == HIGH ? 255 : 0;
    LEDStick.setLEDColor(intensity, intensity, intensity);
  }

  Serial.println("Single coil steps");
  myMotor->step(200, FORWARD, SINGLE);
}
```

Code:

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Adafruit_MotorShield.h>
#include "Qwiic_LED_Stick.h" // Click here to get the library: http://librarymanager/All#SparkFun_Qwiic_LED_Stick

// Variables will change:
int ledState = LOW;             // ledState used to set the LED

unsigned long previousMillis = 0;        // will store last time LED was updated

// constants won't change:
const long interval = 1000;           // interval at which to blink (milliseconds)

LED LEDStick; //Create an object of the LED class
Adafruit_MotorShield AFMS = Adafruit_MotorShield();
Adafruit_StepperMotor *myMotor = AFMS.getStepper(200, 2);

void setup() {
  Wire.begin();
  Serial.begin(115200);
  while (!Serial);
  Serial.println("Stepper test!");

  if (!AFMS.begin()) {
    // if (!AFMS.begin(1000)) {
    Serial.println("Could not find Motor Shield. Check wiring.");
    while (1);
  }
  Serial.println("Motor Shield found.");
  myMotor->setSpeed(50);  // 50 rpm


  //Start up communication with the LED Stick
  if (LEDStick.begin() == false) {
    Serial.println("Qwiic LED Stick failed to begin. Please check wiring and try again!");
    while (1);
  }

  Serial.println("Qwiic LED Stick ready!");
}

void loop() {
  unsigned long currentMillis = millis();

  if (currentMillis - previousMillis >= interval) {
    // save the last time you blinked the LED
    previousMillis = currentMillis;

    // if the LED is off turn it on and vice-versa:
    if (ledState == LOW) {
      ledState = HIGH;
    } else {
      ledState = LOW;
    }

    // set the LED with the ledState of the variable:
    LEDStick.setLEDColor(50, 50, 50);
  }

  Serial.println("Single coil steps");
  myMotor->step(200, FORWARD, SINGLE);
}
```

Comment: `it does not work` is a useless description of a problem ... what actually happens?

Comment: It does not blink properly

Comment: that is just as cryptic ... what were you expecting to happen? ... what actually happened?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only set (assign) `ledState`, but you never use it.

I think the following fragment

```
// set the LED with the ledState of the variable:
LEDStick.setLEDColor(50, 50, 50);
```

Should be something like:

```
// set the LED with the ledState of the variable:
uint8_t intensity = ledState == HIGH ? 255 : 0;
LEDStick.setLEDColor(intensity, intensity, intensity);
```

This 'converts' the ledState into white (RGB values 255) when HIGH or black/off (RGB values 0) when LOW.

Also you can change the line

```
if (LEDStick.begin() == false) {
```

into

```
if (!LEDStick.begin()) {
```

and change the lines

```
// if the LED is off turn it on and vice-versa:
if (ledState == LOW) {
  ledState = HIGH;
} else {
  ledState = LOW;
}
```

into

```
// if the LED is off turn it on and vice-versa:
ledState = ledState == LOW ? HIGH : LOW;
```

or even

```
ledState = !ledState;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I did the modified code and updated it in the question, it seems to blink but longer than 1sec. Can it be related to the board frequency. How can I control different light colors based on this code: uint8_t intensity = ledState == HIGH ? 255 : 0;
LEDStick.setLEDColor(intensity, intensity, intensity);

Comment: Please upvote and accept the answer if it helped and is the solution for your problem.  I don't see directly why it blinks longer than 1 sec, you can print out variables to find out the exact times. About the colors, you can transform LOW/HIGH into any value between 0 and 255 for both red, green and blue, just play a bit with the arguments inside the `LEDStick.setLEDColor` statement.